# PHP: generate unique string for filename

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I want to upload files with an unique random string as file name, then if I upload a file called file.txt that will be hashed like m84n3nv38tu48a, if I upload the same file again it won't be saved because the same file name with that hash exists.

Then download the file searching it by the original name, hashing again and compare to find out in the directory.

Something like this

```
public function storeFile(Request $request) {
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $file->move(storage_path()."\\app\\file", md5_file($file);
    $response = [
        "file Name" => $filename,
        "Extension" => $file->getClientOriginalExtension(),
        "Path" => storage_path().$path
    ];
    return response()->json($response);
}

public function downloadFile($fileName) {
    $fullpath = storage_path()."\\app\\file\\".md5_file($fileName);
    $file = file_exists($fullpath);
    if($file)
        return response()->download($fullpath, $fileName);
    return response()->json('File not Found', 404);
}
```

The md5_file method in downloadFile doesn't (obviously work) because $fileName is a string (not a file) then I get a different hash.

How could I resolve this?

**EDIT**

I want to replace the entire file name with a unique ID.

Comment: Which Laravel version are you on? IIRC, Laravel has supported this functionality automagically since version 5.3 if you use the correct facade. Doesn't necessarily answer your question but might solve it in a very easy way.

Comment: Or maybe use http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

Comment: You will not be able to find your file back if your hash is based on the file content (unless you have already the file content, which would make useless the fact of wanting to retreive it). Calculate the hash on the file name instead (that you know when you want to get it back)

Comment: Use `microtime()` or `uniqid()` and concatenate that to the filename before hashing.

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.6

Comment: @SimoneBattiato Then you might just solve this the easy way by using the `Storage` facade: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: hashing only the file name, if i upload a file with the same file name but with different content won't be uploaded, and doesn't create unique id

Comment: So take the filename and add some random integers or the current unix timestamp to it?

Comment: i want to replace all the file name with an unique id

Comment: @SimoneBattiato Perhaps it would help if you could explain how you expect download to work?  If the filename is the only input to download, that's the only thing you can hash.